# JS Increment not updating in for loop of while using gcs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I would like to create a function that only run when the all the files is copied on GCS.
When running the createNewTemplateFolder function, the "copiedFileAmout" is not updating.

Here is the code on click function

```
const fileNamesToCopy = ['index.html', 'main.css','script.js','video.js','videocss.css'];
const loopFiles = async(request,response) =>{
    console.log(request.body)
    for (const fileNameEach of fileNamesToCopy) {
        const fileName = fileNameEach;
        // console.log(fileName)
        createNewTemplateFolder(bucketName, originalFolder + fileName,bucketName, newFolderPath + fileName, newFolderPath);      
    }   
      
    response.send("Folder Created ok.")
```

then loop thru the files on GCS and copy to new folder.

```
const createNewTemplateFolder = async (srcBucketName, srcFilename, destBucketName,destFileName, destFilePath) =>{
    // Copies the file to the new folder
    let copiedFileAmout = 0;
    await storage
      .bucket(srcBucketName)
      .file(srcFilename)
      .copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFileName))
      .then(() =>{
        console.log('copy done '+ destFileName)
        copyFileStatus = true;
        copiedFileAmout++  /// this is not working
      })
      .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err)
        copiedFileAmout++
      })
      
    if(copiedFileAmout === 5){
        uploadCombineDelete(destFilePath) // This function should only run once when all 5 files is copied
    }
```

Searched on google but not sure if the Promise not able to run the increment.
Hope can get come suggestion on this, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just move the call to `uploadCombineDelete` after the loop? This way it will be called definitely after all files have been copied and you don't have to check for any variable if it has the right value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the variable copiedFileAmout outside the function (global scope).

```
let copiedFileAmout = 0;
const fileNamesToCopy = ['index.html', 'main.css','script.js','video.js','videocss.css'];
const loopFiles = async(request,response) =>{
....
....
```

Then remove the line

```
let copiedFileAmout = 0;
```

from the function createNewTemplateFolder

Comment: @Carol Chaw, can you please let us know if this asnwers your question ?

Comment: oh it is weird that I was declare the 'copiedFileAmout' as global at the very first i started and it not working... but now is working fine after you answered this thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices:

Declare copiedFileAmount outside of the functions so both have access to it

`let copiedFileAmount = 0;`

Or a less favourable approach, just change the declaration of the current variable from let to var which gives it a greater scope.

`var copiedFileAmount = 0;`